# prompt user to save as

Tags: php

My code is like below:

```
$final_img = ''; //some image manipulations
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-image');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=tests.png");

imagepng($final_img);
```

My question is, when people click the anchor, it automatically saves the image with the name tests.png. But if the user right click and save link as, they can save the file into whatever name they want. So, how can I prompt a save as dialog when people click a link?

Comment: There is no such thing as `application/octet-image`. You want `application/octet-stream`. Or even better `image/png` (yes you can - and should - do that even when having the file save to disk).

Comment: it works though when I used octed-image, though I will change it to octet-stream.

Comment: +1, this question is valid and therefore underrated. @Henson, why not use image/png as mime-type? It was defined for that...

Comment: @PelletenCate : thanks for the advice, but it's just an example, I may generate a jpg, gif, or png later.

Comment: @Henson Well, there's also image/jpeg and image/gif for that purpose. Best is to be as specific as possible in your content-type. (It's not that tough to write a few conditional lines for it, is it?) Otherwise, application/octet-stream is the way to go indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the user has download settings set to "default to X location". You cannot control this. Let the user do what they want with the file and stop trying to meddle with his/her workflow.

Comment: You do have some control over the file name though, if the user sends it to the server along with the download request. See answer.

Comment: @PelletenCate: Not the path. Trying to re-invent the browser's behaviour is "wrong".

Comment: True, though the question implicated that the file name is the subject. The ethical view on this solution is argumentative, and in my opinion highly depends on the use case. I do think it's a bit early to just call it "wrong".

Comment: I don't really care about the path though, just the file name.

Comment: @Henson: Your user cares about the path. Why do you have such little regard for what your user cares about? Your user is more important than you... and it's your user's computer that you're downloading on to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It depends on users browsers' settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do what you're asking for in the way you suggest. You can however explicitly ask the user for a file name, using this:

```
<form action="download.php" method="get">
  <label>File name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="filename" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download image" />
</form>
```

download.php:

```
$final_img = ''; //some image manipulations

/* Fetch filename and ensure it ends with '.png'. */
/* @todo strip unacceptable characters, e.g. slashes etc. */
$fileName = trim($_GET['filename']);
if (strtolower(substr($fileName,-4)) != '.png') $fileName .= '.png'

/* Send the headers */
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");

/* Send the image data */
imagepng($final_img);
```

Comment: sure, though it's quite strange to use a form to ask users to input what his file name is gonna be. I just thought "if it ain't broke, don't fix it", cos the general flow of downloading is we click, we choose where we want to save, what the name is, and click Save. Guess the browsers take care of it now

Comment: Well, if the browser is auto-saving the file, what is changed to that flow? We chose a file name, we click the 'Save' button (that I called 'download file' in this example), and the browser does the rest behind our backs. We just don't get to choose the path...

Comment: yeah, i mean, using a form rather than a simple anchor to download (IMO) is just a bit weird in the user experience. Using a download manager prompts us to change the file name though, so there's that I guess.

Comment: Well, as far as user experience is of importance, of course you don't need it to look like a form... You can add an anchor tag as well instead of a submit button, and submit the form using javascript. (I do that all the time.). Or even not submit a form at all, but just do a `window.location` with the file name added to the query string. My point is: the presentation should not strictly implicate a certain implementation in my opinion. You can even make it look completely like a "save as" window, although you don't have the real file list.